# javascript - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, promise

I would like to understand this behavior of `Promise.all`.

```
  var checkIfModuleExists = promisify(
    function (m, cb){
      var doc = {
        index: 'app1',
        type: 'm1',
        id: m.id,
        body: { }
      };
      client.exists(doc ,
        function (err, exists) {
          cb(err, exists);
        });
    });
```

and then I have a `promise.all` like this:

```
var module = [{id: 'aa'}, {id: 'bb'}];
Promise.all( modules.map(function(module){
      return checkIfModuleExists(module);
    })).then(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
```

When I run this 'then' show [false, true]: this seems normal, but what I don't understand is that if I change my callback function like this `cb({exists: exists, m: m}, err);`, I receive only json, there is no more array. I would like to receive array containing m and if the module exists or not (something like this : [{m: true/false}, {m: true/false}]). Can you please explain this behavior and how to can get an array containing every module an his status ? Thanks

Comment: The signature of the callback is `(error, successValue)`, so you should call `cb(err, { m: exists }` - you had the parameters the wrong way around

Comment: Per CodingIntrigue's comment, this appears to have nothing to do with `Promise.all()` at all so your question title is a bit off the mark.  You'd have the same issue if you called `checkIfModuleExists().then()` all by itself.

Comment: Please describe your actual question in your title. As it stands, your title would apply to half the questions posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you confused the error and result parameters. What happens is that the first promise will reject, causing your error handler to be executed with the object you expected.

However, this isn't how you should use `promisify` anyway. Rather do

```
var clientExists = promisify(client.exists, {context:client});
function checkIfModuleExists(m) {
    return clientExists({
        index: 'app1',
        type: 'm1',
        id: m.id,
        body: { }
    }).then(function(exists) {
        return {exists: exists, m: m};
    });
}
```